# ExtJS. Can i put new cells or rows into rendered panel, with layout : 'table'

Tags: javascript, extjs

For Example:

```
var tablePanel = new Ext.Panel({
        border: false,
        autoScroll: true,
        layout: 'table',
        layoutConfig: { columns: maxColumns },
        items: items
    });
```

Can i add rows or cells to that table? And how can i do that? with method .add or? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think so.

```
tablePanel.add(whatever);
tablePanel.add(whatever2);
tablePanel.add(whatever3);
tablePanel.add(whatever4);
...
tablePanel.doLayout();
```

In the table layout, there are no explicite row objects; just every group of *n* columns are one row (ignoring rowspan and colspan), *n* being the value of `layoutConfig: { columns: n }`

Comment: -1, if you're ever adding a component to a container, it should go through the container add method, not be poked into the items collection.